# How to set multiple default values for multiselect select tag in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multi-select

How can I set multiple default values for a multiselect select tag in Angular?  Here is my tag:

```
 <select multiple="multiple"
            class="form-control multiselect"
            ng-model="dog.Tags"
            ng-options="tag as tag.Name for tag in tagsAvailable">
 </select>
```

I have an ajax call in a service that is called in my controller which returns the Dog object. The Dog object looks something like:

```
{ID: 1, Name: "Lassie", Tags: [{TagID: 2, Name: "Red"},{TagID: 3, Name: "Barker"}]}
```

Here is the method in my controller that calls the service that returns the Dog JSON object.

```
dogSvc.getDog($routeParams.dogId).then(
            function (response) {
               $scope.dog = response.data;
            },
           function (response) {
               $scope.status = response.status;
       });
```

I want to set the default selected values to the Dog.Tags values.

Then I have a similar service that returns all of the available tags, which I want to populate as options in the select box.

```
tagSvc.getAllTags().then(
    function (response) {
        $scope.tagsAvailable = response.data;
    },
    function (response) {
        $scope.status = response.status;
    });
```

The available tags populate, but no default values are populated.  How can I preselect options based on my returned Dog object's tags?

Comment: For each of the options you need to add a `selected` attribute.

Comment: How is this achieved in angular?  I am using an angular directive to create my option tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```
$q.all([tagSvc.getAllTags(), dogSvc.getDog($routeParams.dogId)]).then(
    function (responses) {
        $scope.tagsAvailable = responses[0].data;
        $scope.dog = responses[1].data;
        $scope.dog.Tags = $scope.tagsAvailable.filter(
                 function (tag) {
                     return $scope.dog.Tags.some(
                         function (elem) {
                             if (elem.TagID == tag.TagID) return true;
                         });
                 });

    });
```

Basically this:

1. Retrieves the available tags.
2. Retrieves the existing tags, which will become the defaults.
3. Takes the available tags and filters them so that only the available tags that are present in the existing tags array are included.
4. Sets the filtered available tags as the model's tags value.